# Discord js random mention bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a command that randomly give you percentage when you do -komanda. I just couldn't make to it says if no one is mentioned to mention someone and doesn't give me a undefined is 90%. This is my code:

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');


module.exports = class SayCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('komanda', 'fun', []);
  }

async  run(client, message, args) {
  var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    let mention = message.mentions.users.first()
    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
    const messageToSay = args.join(" ");
    const sayEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    message.channel.send(`${mention} je \xa0${rating}%\xa0\ bad man`)

  
      try {
      } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          message.channel.send("JA ZIVKOVIC SLOBODAN NE SMEM TO DA KAZEM");
        }
      }

  }
```

When i do -komanda @USER it will show:
@USER je 90% bad man
but if i dont mention anyone it will say undefined

Comment: Well, what do you want to output if no user has been mentioned?

Comment: like, please mention a user or something like that

Comment: Does it always return 90% if there is a mention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output a warning when no user has been mentioned, just check if `mention` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy):

```js
if (!mention) return // ...
```

---

For example, in your code:

```js
let rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
let mention = message.mentions.users.first();

if (!mention) return message.channel.send("Please mention a user!");

message.channel.send(`${mention} je \xa0${rating}%\xa0\ bad man`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `<channel>.send(...)` check if there is mention:

```js
if (!mention) return message.channel.send("Please mention");
```

Comment: it already returns undefined if no mention